# Out of memory. - Webview android

Tags: android, webview

[FATAL:memory_linux.cc(35)] Out of memory.
webview app get crashed when i have opened it from last one hour
how can we treat to this bug ?

how can we assign more memory to webview process ?

Comment: Do you run some Javascript that probably has a memory leak inside the web view?

Comment: Yes, javascript called at every 10 seconds.so memory leak occurred